# Haskell: Multi-way if-expressions need MultiWayIf turned on

Tags: haskell, ghc

Trying to build with "stack build":

```
module Main where


analyzeGold :: Int -> String
analyzeGold standard =
  if | standard == 999 -> "Wow! 999 standard!"
     | standard == 750 -> "Great! 750 standard."
     | standard == 585 -> "Not bad! 585 standard."
     | otherwise -> "I don't know such a standard..."

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn (analyzeGold 999)
```

And I got:

```
    Multi-way if-expressions need MultiWayIf turned on
  |
6 |   if | standard == 999 -> "Wow! 999 standard!"
  |   ^^
```

How to fix it?

stack 1.7.1, GHC 8.2.2

Comment: Well a multiway-if is iimply those guards, without the if.

Comment: If you really want to use that, you can turn on that extension putting `{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}` at the top of your file. (You can also turn it on in the  stack config file -- I always forget the exact syntax, though)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well in Haskell there is only an `if`-`then`-`else` clause. If you want these "*multi-if*" statements, you use a *guard*.

## Using *guards*

Your syntax is already rather close to a guard, except that it does *not* have an **`if`** keyword, and that the equality sign (**`=`**) is used to denote what the output is in that case.

So you should rewrite it to:

```
analyzeGold :: Int -> String
analyzeGold standard
    | standard == 999 = "Wow! 999 standard!"
    | standard == 750 = "Great! 750 standard."
    | standard == 585 = "Not bad! 585 standard."
    | otherwise = "I don't know such a standard..."
```

See [here [lyah]](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards) for some information about the syntax and use of guards.

## Using *pattern*s

Since your checks each time check equality of integer literals, we can actually move the checks from the guards to the patterns, like:

```
analyzeGold :: Int -> String
analyzeGold 999 = "Wow! 999 standard!"
analyzeGold 750 = "Great! 750 standard."
analyzeGold 585 = "Not bad! 585 standard."
analyzeGold _ = "I don't know such a standard..."
```

Here the underscore (`_`) acts as a *wildcard* that matches all values (well all patterns that are not matched by earlier clauses).

## Using the `MultiWayIf` extension

You can also enable a GHCi extension to enable this extension, by writing a pragma in the head of the file, or by using `-XMultiWayIf` when invoking the interpreter. So:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

analyzeGold :: Int -> String
analyzeGold standard =
    if | standard == 999 -> "Wow! 999 standard!"
       | standard == 750 -> "Great! 750 standard."
       | standard == 585 -> "Not bad! 585 standard."
       | otherwise -> "I don't know such a standard..."
```

Or:

```
$ ghci -XMultiWayIf
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :{
Prelude| analyzeGold :: Int -> String
Prelude| analyzeGold standard =
Prelude|     if | standard == 999 -> "Wow! 999 standard!"
Prelude|        | standard == 750 -> "Great! 750 standard."
Prelude|        | standard == 585 -> "Not bad! 585 standard."
Prelude|        | otherwise -> "I don't know such a standard..."
Prelude| :}
```

Comment: His file works fine as-is (no edits needed) with `-XMultiWayIf` turned on, as suggested by the error message.

Comment: I believe the `-X` flags should only be used for GHCi. When compiling a proper module, you should use `LANGUAGE` pragmas or *maybe* a `default-extensions` field in a `.cabal` file. The latter is useful when your package uses a lot of extensions and uses them everywhere, but it makes it a bit harder for readers to see what extensions are in play in a module.